# Why can't I set cookies over HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-eks

I have a server that has its own domain and is using HTTPS. I have [a website](https://chathub.ninja) that has its own domain and is using HTTPS as well.

On the home page of the website, there is a login button and a sign up button. Both buttons lead to forms to execute their respective tasks, and both forms send requests to the server that respond with cookies, or at least that's what they are supposed to do.

I am using `express-session` in combination with `Redis` to store the session ids. Here is the config for that (`connectToRedis` is simply a function that returns a `RedisClient`):

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = await connectToRedis();
app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
      }),
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "lax",
        maxAge: TEN_YEARS,
      },
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      secret: SECRET,
      name: AUTH_COOKIE,
    })
  );
```

For some reason the cookies are not being sent in the requests. The `Set-Cookie` header isn't even showing up! I tried changing `SameSite` to none ([article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)), but that didn't work.

This is my first time deploying a production website, so all this HTTPS stuff is kind of new to me.

Thanks for your help, and if you need any extra information, please let me know.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

Finally, I have made some progress (all it took was a pizza break).

I added the `path` key to my cookie config and gave it the value of `/`. I also set `proxy` to true.

So now it looks like this:

```
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
  const redisClient = await connectToRedis();

  app.use(
    session({
      store: new RedisStore({
        client: redisClient,
      }),
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        maxAge: TEN_YEARS,
        path: "/",
      },
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      secret: SECRET,
      name: AUTH_COOKIE,
      proxy: true,
    })
  );
```

With this, the cookie is finally appearing in the requests, but it isn't being set in the browser...